# Unable to start webdriver-manager on mac to test angular apps on protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, npm, protractor

I am new to [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/). While starting the Selenium Server using `webdriver-manager` in [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) I am getting the following error

```
 [19:32:29] I/start - java Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.31 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.18.0 -jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar -port 4444
 [19:32:29] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 823 Error: Unable to access jarfile /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar
 [19:32:29] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1 
 AgIwals-MacBook-Pro:angulartestingprotractor agiwal$ Error: Unable to access jarfile /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar
```

My `protractor` version is `5.1.2` and my `npm` version is `3.10.10`. Can somebody help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to update `webdriver-manager` - a new version was [released yesterday](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.5/) so your timing is coincidental.  You can also see the language bindings release dates here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/.  And since you mentioned you're on Protractor v5+, you should also confirm that your `node` (not npm) version is v6+.

You simply need to run `webdriver-manager update` -- personally I like to avoid potential driver/version conflicts by cleaning out any old downloads via `webdriver-manager clean`, but that's up to you (run the update after clean).